Execute XSLT in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I have a VSTO Visio Addin that is built using Azure DevOps CICD.
As part of the pipeline I would like a stage task to automate the execution of a XSLT that will process various Visual Studio *.csproj files to generate a JSON that can be deployed with the VSTO Addin.
I have developed a XSLT that works fine from the command line, however it is not clear how I might automate this is the CICD pipeline build. Looking at the MS pipeline tasks, it seems thta I might implement the following:

Call an Azure Function using AzureFunction@1
Call a REST API using InvokeRESTAPI@1
Write a VS test that could be called using VSTest@3

Is there any CLI and/or Powershell support that would be simpler and more light weight?
Any thoughts would be gratefully received.
Cheers,
Andrew

This is supported by Powershell - sample code below for the CICD task
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     $Xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
     $PathToXsltFile = "$pwd\transformer.xslt"
     $XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings
     $XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction=1
     $XmlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
     $Xslt.Load($PathToXsltFile, $XsltSettings, $XmlResolver)
     $Xslt.Transform("$pwd\source.xml", "$pwd\target.xml")


Thanks for sharing! It also works for me. You can accept your answer to make the solution clearer.
